# Computing the browser's scrollbar size

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

There is another question asking how to calculate the browser's scrollbar sizes.

My question is about the solution implemented in the npm package [scrollbar-wdith](https://github.com/olmokramer/scrollbar-width.js/blob/4e9d07b19d9328fe39053c0dd0a799deaf1af87b/scrollbar-width.js).  Can somebody explain why it works?

For reference, here is the relevant code (.coffee):

```
scrollbarWidth = null

getScrollbarWidth = (recalculate = false) ->
  return scrollbarWidth if scrollbarWidth? and not recalculate

  return null if document.readyState is 'loading'

  div1 = document.createElement 'div'
  div2 = document.createElement 'div'

  div1.style.width = div2.style.width = div1.style.height = div2.style.height = '100px'
  div1.style.overflow = 'scroll'
  div2.style.overflow = 'hidden'

  document.body.appendChild div1
  document.body.appendChild div2

  scrollbarWidth = Math.abs div1.scrollHeight - div2.scrollHeight

  document.body.removeChild div1
  document.body.removeChild div2

  scrollbarWidth
```

Comment: Because `scrollHeight` changes based on the height of the scrollbars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what i did. Took the crux of the code and simplified it a bit.

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
<script>
  var scrollbarWidth;

  scrollbarWidth = null;

  getScrollbarWidth = function(recalculate) {
    var div1, div2;
    div1 = document.createElement('div');
    div2 = document.createElement('div');
    div1.id = "div1";
    div2.id = "div2";
    div1.style.width = div2.style.width = div1.style.height = div2.style.height = '100px';
    div1.style.overflow = 'scroll';
    div2.style.overflow = 'hidden';
    document.body.appendChild(div1);
    document.body.appendChild(div2);
    scrollbarWidth = Math.abs(div1.scrollHeight - div2.scrollHeight);
    alert(scrollbarWidth);
    return scrollbarWidth;
  };

  getScrollbarWidth();

</script>
<html>
```

This let me play around with the elements.

what happens is that they create two identical divs, one with a scroll bar and another without a scrollbar and then they query the scrollHeight property for both of them, which ignores the scrollbar (just the element and padding).. see here - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_scrollheight.asp

> The scrollHeight property returns the entire height of an element in pixels, including padding, but not the border, **scrollbar** or margin.

the difference in the scrollHeights yields the required scrollbar's height (since one of the elements has a scrollbar and the other one does not)

as it turns out, div2 scrollHeight = 100 px (=height) while div1's scrollHeight was only 83px and so chrome has a scrollbar of height 17px

Let me know if that makes sense to you

Comment: Makes sense.  Guess I was confused--thought the code was measuring the height of a vertical scrollbar... not used to seeing horizontal scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simpler snipped that also sets the scrollbar's pixel size to a CSS custom property of `--scrollbar` (if your browser supports the spec):

```
(function(node, body){
  node.style.display = 'inline-block';
  node.style.position = 'absolute';
  node.style.height = '0';
  node.style.overflow = 'scroll';
  body.appendChild(node);
  body.style.setProperty('--scrollbar', node.offsetWidth + 'px');
  body.removeChild(node);
})(document.createElement('scrollbartester'), document.body);
```